# How to generate a JFreeChart with only CMYK Colors

Tags: java, itext, jfreechart

How to generate a JFreeChart with CMYK Colors only?

Do I have to call all the `.setPaint(new CmykColor(...))` or is there a more elegant way?
Even I don't know all the possible `.setPaint(...)` methods.

To reproduce the problem I wrote a small unit test. It generates a Chart and finally it adds it to PDF/x that only allows CMYK.

The test goes green if no `com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfXConformanceException`: Colorspace RGB is not allowed. Exception is thrown.

```
public class TestChart
{
    public static final int WIDTH   = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT  = 400;

    private JFreeChart      chart;

    @Before
    public void createChart()
    {
        final DefaultPieDataset dataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataSet.setValue("United States", 4.54);
        dataSet.setValue("Brazil", 2.83);

        this.chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("World Population by countries", dataSet, true, true, false);

//      ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("test.png"), chart, width, height);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddChartToPdfX() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException
    {
        final Document document = new Document();
        document.addTitle("Test PDF/x");

        final PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
        pdfWriter.setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFX1A2001);

        document.open();

        final PdfContentByte directContent = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
        final PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = directContent.createTemplate(TestChart.WIDTH, TestChart.HEIGHT);
        final Graphics2D graphics2d = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(TestChart.WIDTH, TestChart.HEIGHT);

        final Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, TestChart.WIDTH, TestChart.HEIGHT);

        this.chart.draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);

        graphics2d.dispose();

        directContent.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 0, 0);

        document.close();

    }
}
```

To execute this you need this maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can change the colors that the plot will use for your different datasets by calling plot.setDrawingSupplier() and providing one with the colors you like (you can use the ChartColor class if it helps). It's an interface so you can make your own or you can use DefaultDrawingSupplier and it's multiarg constuctor to make it simpler. Then there's setOutlinePaint, setBackgroundPaint and, just in case, setNoDataPaint. That should cover most things except tick marks, etc. which are already grey I believe.